# "Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException" in JUnit, despite throwing it in normal class?

Tags: java, exception, junit

Brace yourselves, Java beginner here. I wrote a method that reads a file to an integer array list.

```
 public static ArrayList<Integer> numArray(String numIn) throws FileNotFoundException{  

    try{
        FileReader file = new FileReader(numIn);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
           statusCodes.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
        sc.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return statusCodes;
    }
```

It works fine when I run it in the main method of its own class, but when I try to run a JUnit Test Case for it, it gives me a FileNotFoundException.

```
static ArrayList<Integer> newCodes = numArray("src/statCodes.txt");
```

Does anybody know how to get rid of this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of declaring `throws FileNotFoundException` as you are catching `Exception` which will catch all Exceptions including catched and untcached(Runtime) Exception.

You are getting `FileNotFoundException` because file is not found at the path you have specified. Maybe try using absolute path? Check what is the root folder of your project and provide path accordingly. Also it will depend where are you running your junit cases from.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your method declares a (wrong) throwing of FileNotFoundException, which is caught in itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because it is not able to find your file from directory. A good way to do this `YourTestClass.class.getResourceAsStream(filename)`, this will return an InputStream. Also as everyone said, either remove your catch or throws clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your catch statement catches ALL exceptions and doesn't re-throw them, so this method doesn't need the throw statement. Also if you have a method that throws an exception any time that method is called you must handle the exception that it throws.

Also are you running the JUnit tests inside the same package? I can't imagine that you wouldn't be but at least in eclipse it looks for the file in the local directory,which is the same for the JUnit and the main class.

Answer (score 0):

Despite all the answers telling you that you don't need to throw an exception if you catch it, the reason you're likely getting the `FileNotFoundException` when you run your tests using JUnit is because your test classes are likely in a different directory and your path to the file is not valid in that situation. Try examining the value of `numIn` relative to your test classes and see if using an absolute path or some other solution works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgotten to add another "throws FileNotFoundException" to the main method of your test case.